# Need some help completing this aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I have an analytics collection where I store queries as individual documents. I want to count the number of queries taking place over the past day (24 hours). Here's the aggregation command as it is:

```
db.analytics.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"day":{$dayOfMonth:"$datetime"},"hour":{$hour:"$datetime"}},"count":{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{"_id.day":1,"_id.hour":1}}])
```

The result looks like:

```
.
.
.
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : 17,
                "hour" : 19
            },
            "count" : 8
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : 17,
                "hour" : 22
            },
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : 18,
                "hour" : 0
            },
            "count" : 1
        }
.
.
.
```

Originally, my plan was to add a `$limit` operation to simply take the last 24 results. That's a great plan until you realize that there are some hours without any queries at all. So the last 24 documents could go back more than a single day. I thought of using `$match`, but I'm just not sure how to go about constructing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the day just as current date or as most recent document from the collection. Then use query for specified day like:

```
db.analytics.aggregate([
    {$project:{datetime:"$datetime",day:{$dayOfMonth:"$datetime"}}},
    {$match:{day:3}},
    {$group:{_id:{"hour":{$hour:"$datetime"}},"count":{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{"_id.hour":1}}
]);
```

where 3 is the day of the month here {$match:{day:***3***}}

The idea is to add a day field, so, we able to filter by it, then group documents of the day by hours and sort.